# XtraGrid - GrdView - Evento ao clicar

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

Galera bom dia.
Como vai?

Estou com uma dificuldade, em implementar um evento ao clicar no GridView.
Estou utilizando os componentes do DevExpress, XtraGrid.GridView.

Bom, estou adicionando o evento:

```
this.gridView1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.click_datagridview1);
```

que chama meu metodo:

```
 private void click_datagridview1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string v = Convert.ToString(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0], "ID")); //sintexe correta
        MessageBox.Show("Valor da coluna ID " + v);
    }
```

Porém, ao clicar na tabela, nada acontece, fui atras da documentação no site do DevExpress, e encontrei: [Site Help DevExpress](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_Clicktopic)

The Click event occurs when the end-user clicks within a View. If clicking a grid cell activates a column editor, the Click event does not occur. Before the Click event, the MouseDown event is generated. This occurs whenever the end-user presses the mouse key.

Please refer to the Hit Information Overview topic for information on how to determine which element has been clicked.

Pelo que entendi, se a edição de colunas estiver ativada, o evento não ocorre, é isso? alguém poderia me dar esclarecida?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Galera é isso ai.

Se a edição de colunas estiver ativada, o evento não ocorre.

Para o evento Click ocorrer, deve-se adicionar a linha abaixo nas opções do gridview:

```
AllowEdit = False
```

Valeu